# Directory not found error in WCF service call in IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, iis

I am using asp.net 3.5 with c#

In my web application there is a folder named `SlideShow` which contain images. I want to  get the name of images with respective URL and return it in JSON format using WCF. I have created a method that returns json string contains image path and array of images. It is  working fine when i run the application with ASP.NET development server, but gives error on IIS.

My interface is

```
[OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
        Stream GetSlideShowImages();
```

service method is

```
   Stream Iremoteclient.GetSlideShowImages()
        {
                byte[] resultBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(new AndroidServices().GetSlideShowImages());
                WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "text/plain";
                saveAndroidRequest();
                return new MemoryStream(resultBytes);
            }

        }
```

and Method to get json string from  is

```
public string GetSlideShowImages()
        {
            try
            {
                string relativepath = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Scheme + "://" + HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Authority + HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath;

                string pathlastchr = relativepath.Trim().Substring(relativepath.Length - 1, 1);
                if (pathlastchr == "/")
                {
                    relativepath = relativepath.Trim() + "SlideShow/";
                }
                else
                {
                    relativepath = relativepath.Trim() + "SlideShow/";
                }
                string json;
                DirectoryInfo directoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/SlideShow"));
                FileInfo[] file = directoryInfo.GetFiles().Where(f => f.Extension == (".bmp") || f.Extension == (".jpg") || f.Extension == (".png") || f.Extension == (".TIFF") || f.Extension == (".gif")).ToArray();

                AndroidServices objAndroidServices = new AndroidServices();
                objAndroidServices.ImagePath = relativepath;
                objAndroidServices.Images = file.Select(f => f.Name).ToArray();


                using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(AndroidServices));
                    ser.WriteObject(ms, objAndroidServices);
                    json = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.GetBuffer(), 0, Convert.ToInt16(ms.Length));
                    json = json.Replace(@"\/", @"/");
                }
                return json;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {                   
                return ex.Message;
            }
        }
```

On IIS it gives error like

> "   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String
>   maybeFullPath)     at
>   System.IO.Directory.InternalGetFileDirectoryNames(String path, String
>   userPathOriginal, String searchPattern, Boolean i" and 
>   "   at System.Text.Encoding.GetBytes(String s)     at
>   ihv1Role.service.remoteclient.ihv1Role.service.Iremoteclient.GetSlideShowImages()
>   in E:\VivifyHealth\caregiverihportal\src\service\remoteclient.svc"

Any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the issue is that you need to change this:

```
DirectoryInfo directoryInfo =
    new DirectoryInfo(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/SlideShow"));
```

to this:

```
DirectoryInfo directoryInfo =
    new DirectoryInfo(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/SlideShow"));
```

Per the MSDN documentation:

> ... the slash (/) at the beginning of the path indicates an absolute virtual path to the site.

However, when you preface it with the `~` it will start in the root of the site.